# Populate newsletter HTML template with data from Google Sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Is it possible to populate HTML template with data from google sheets? I assume it is possible, so if anyone worked on this - can you just give me example or guidance which way is best, per your experience?

To be clear - I have ready HTML newsletter template and have data in Google Sheeet which we now copy everyday from sheet to template, so that is the purpose of this - to avoid manual work as much as possible.

Thank you...

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: This is a general question, where I am searching for documentation or/tutorial, not to have something ready-made for me - so in general is anyone worked before on automated population of fields in external HTML document using google sheet, and if so what did you use - PHP, Laravel...as a intermediate connector

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [Google Apps Script - HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

It helps you create HTML templates and populate them with data from Google sheets.

It uses Google Apps Script, which is a JavaScript-based language.